# how to get multiple XML elements attributes with php simpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have this XML

```
<STOREITEMS>
  <CREATED value="Tue Oct 9 5:30:01 BST 2012">
    <CATEGORY id="442" name="Hen And Stag Nights"></CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY id="69" name="Games"></CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY id="252" name="Love Zone"></CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY id="202" name="Spotlight  Items"></CATEGORY>
  </CREATED>
</STOREITEMS>
```

I need to get the Category - name attribute with PHP

So far I have this

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.dropshipping.co.uk/catalog/xml_id_multi_info.xml");

foreach($xml->CATEGORY['name']->attributes() as $category)    
{    
    echo $category; 
}
```

This however returns Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `CATEGORY` nodes are nested inside the `CREATED` node, so you'd need to access it there, and accessing `CATEGORY['name']->attributes()` makes no sense, since that would try to access non-existent attributes on the `name` attribute of the first `CATEGORY` node.

So do you want to retreive the name attribute values of all `CATEGORY` nodes, or all `CATEGORY` nodes, or maybe only those `CATEGORY` nodes that have a `name` attribute?

All `CATEGORY` nodes:

```
foreach($xml->CREATED->CATEGORY as $category)
{
    echo $category['name'] . '<br />';
}
```

Only the `CATEGORY` nodes name attributes:

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//CATEGORY/@name') as $name)
{
    echo $name . '<br />';
}
```

Only the `CATEGORY` nodes that have a name attribute:

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//CATEGORY[@name]') as $category)
{
    echo $category['name'] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! The code for all CATEGORY nodes is what I am looking for and your explanation has helped me understand the way this works.

Comment: One thing worth adding to this is that if doing anything other than echoing your results, remember to cast to string once you are done traversing the XML (e.g. `$my_category_list[] = (string)$category['name'];`) otherwise you will be passing around SimpleXML objects which may have undesirable consequences.